# Best Multienant Approach for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, multi-tenant, mlab

There are multiple approaches for multitenancy in Mongo DB

1) Shared collection with tenantId as discriminator.
2) Collection per tenant.
3) Database per tenant.
4) Database instance per tenant.

I personally prefer third approach but I am not sure which among these can be preferable if I have many tenant. Also, which among these approach  would be a great choice if I want control the impact of tenant on other, espacially, where tenants data is expected to vary a lot in volume.

Comment: Best by what criteria?

Comment: Best in terms of scalability and resource management.